# Terminal background color not always properly reset using "\033[0m"

Tags: c, bash, macos, unix, terminal

Trying to understand terminal behavior when it comes to reset background color on a Unix-like OS (Mac, Linux).

Consider a bash script

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

printf "\033[46m"
printf "On Cyan\n"
printf "\033[0m"
printf "Back to Normal\n"
```

When I initially run this script, everything is as expected. However, if I repeat it for several times, the printing result changes. Following `"Back to Normal"` is a line on cyan background color.

The screenshot (Terminal, Mac OS Mojave):

[image]

Questions:

1. Why is this? Can anyone explain this behavior?
2. If I **have changed background color and have printed out a line (ending with newline)**, what can I do to properly reset the background and to avoid this unwanted trailing background color?

*For your information, I have tested this behavior on Mac OS Mojave Terminal, and on Ubuntu 18.04 Terminal. And I have tested using an equivalent Python 3 script. Results are consistent. I also tried using `fflush(stdout)` in C/C++ but in vain.*

P.S. This question stems from a C++ program to be run on Mac or Linux. I thought it is irrelevant to the language itself, so I simplified it down to a bash script. **If possible, please suggest a solution that can be done in C/C++.**

Comment: To fix: `tput sgr0`; not quite sure why it happens in the first place, though.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Thanks. Just tried `tput sgr0` before running the script. Doesn't work, however. Problem still is there.

Comment: To be precise, I have tried to insert `tput sgr0` before and after `printf "\033[0m"`. But, as before, after repeating the script for around 10 times, the problem comes back again.

Comment: I am running the same script on bash terminal but I am unable to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @PrateekJoshi Hi. This problem usually appears after you quickly repeating it for around 5-10 times. Did you repeat it quickly (say use up arrow keys + enter) and for enough times?

Comment: @aafulei Yes I did ran it continuously for more than 10 times.

Comment: Another observation is that once the problem appears (trailing background color), it will persist in all the following runs, until you enter `clear` command or restart terminal.

Comment: @PrateekJoshi Thanks. Can you report your environment? I am on a Mac OS Mojave and the problem happens both on the built-in Terminal (bash) and an iTerm with zsh.

Comment: Even running while [ 1 ] ;  do ./test.sh ; done on terminal is not reproducing it . I am using GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1) on Debian.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200627/discussion-between-aafulei-and-prateek-joshi).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your issue is caused by the terminal scrolling.

When your "On Cyan" cyan background issue a newline that causes the terminal to scroll, the background of the inserted blank line is filled with the current known background: cyan.

Then you reset the color attribute and your "Back to normal" text prints with the default background, but the area of the line that has not been overwritten, is still cyan.

You should reset the attributes before reaching the end of the line like this:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

printf "\033[46m"
printf "On Cyan"
printf "\033[0m"
printf "\nBack to Normal\n"
```

Alternatively you could issue a clear to end of line `tput el` or `printf "\033[K"` after resetting the text attributes:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

printf "\033[46m" # same as tput setab 6
printf "On Cyan\n"
printf "\033[0m\033[K" # same as tput -S <<<$'sgr0\nel'
printf "Back to Normal\n"
```

Comment: Thanks for answering the first question. What I didn't know was that it was because of **terminal scrolling**. It makes much sense now! I also noticed that if I do `printf "\033[46mOn Cyan\033[0m\n"` there would be no problem. So in this way does it mean that there is no feasible solution to my second question (what to do to reset if I **have issued a newline**)?

Comment: This is the reason you should always reset the attributes before a newline or before reaching the current terminal width or reaching the last column. Use `tput cols` to query the terminal width, and `tput lines` to query the terminal height; so you can control your text flow and avoid leaking attributes to inserted lines while scrolling.

Comment: Thanks! Frankly I am not familiar with `tput`. Is it possible to achieve this effect in C (by including standard libraries or libraries that are shipped on all Unix-like OS like the `<windows.h>` header on Windows)?

Comment: In C or C++, use `#include <ncurses.h>` and its methods to do the same, and even more advanced stuffs than what the `tput` command is capable of.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and suggestion! **Terminal scrolling** is the culprit. I was about to report `ncurses` as my findings :)

Comment: @LéaGris The old library to lookup terminal information is `<termcap.h>` and its functions were embedded in a library which meant to make screen based positioning easier, called `<curses.h>`, which had a newer version released; hence `<ncurses.h>`.  This lineage means that sometimes you can use the documentation for one library in understanding another's calls, although it's not always perfect.  What you want (for width) is the `co` key in the termcap database, https://www.gnu.org/software/termutils/manual/termcap-1.3/html_mono/termcap.html covers terminal commands well.